# ios socket programming - NSStream not working

Tags: ios, sockets, nsstream

I am using a device called a WiFly that has ip address:169.254.1.1 and port 2000. I am trying to connect to this device via an iOS application. I use the following code to connect:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

UInt32 port = 2000;
CFStringRef host = CFSTR("169.254.1.1");

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

// set the delegates to this view controller
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

// Set run loops to continuous receive information
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

// Finally, open the connection
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

Then I use the following to handle stream events:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if (theStream == inputStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output) {
                            NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                            [self messageReceived:output];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"Can't connect to server");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
```

So, I can see that the first two streams are opened correctly. Then it follows immediately with a stream event 4, which from my understanding is to be expected. However, I then try to call a function:

```
- (IBAction)moveForward
{
    NSLog(@"move forward called");
    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}
```

Which should return "forward" from an arduino uno via the wifly. However, when I click, I get another NSStreamEvent 4 for some reason. I also telnetted in to the device via the terminal with:

> telnet 169.254.1.1 2000

and subsequently type a "2"... This returned the desired "forward" immediately. What am I doing wrong from the perspective of the iPad?

Additionally, this code was working a couple weeks ago. But once I updated the simulator, it stopped working... The connection is opening properly, but the arduino device does not seem to be getting the output from the iOS.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

NSStreamEvent 4 is NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable.
You must wait until your output stream has available space before sending data.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace 
NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
with this
NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",2];
in moveForward method.